# Compiling error, MinGW(g++), kinect for windows API

Tags: c++, windows, g++, kinect

New to Kinect development. I want to use MinGW as development environment for my Kinect for windows.

I have installed Kinect for windows SDK under c:\program files\Microsoft SDKS\kinect\v1.8. Then following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973080.aspx) from MSDN, I wrote a code to initialize my Kinect sensor.

When I compile using:

```
g++ -c color.c -I "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc"
```

I got a whole bunch of warnings and errors

1. **Warnings**

   ```
       In file included from NuiApi.h:109:0, from color.c:2:
       c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiSensor.h:137:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #
       endif directive [enabled by default]
       #endif _Vector4_
               ^
       c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiSensor.h:160:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #
       endif directive [enabled by default]
       #endif _Matrix4_
               ^
       c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiSensor.h:209:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #
       endif directive [enabled by default]
       #endif _NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_INDEX_
       ...
       ...
   ```

   From I what I have searched, these warning are cause by compiler differences because Kinect SDK is intended for Visual Studio and they are egnorable.
2. **Errors**

   ```
   NuiApi.h:47:5: error: definition of 'HRESULT NuiInitialize' is marked 'dllimport'

   NuiApi.h:47:5: error: '_In_' was not declared in this scope

   NuiApi.h:77:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
     static_assert(E_NUI_FRAME_NO_DATA == 0x83010001, "Error code has changed.");
                  ^

   In file included from NuiApi.h:109:0,
                from color.c:2:
   c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiSensor.h:2105:1: error:    '_Check_return_' does not name a type
   _Check_return_ HRESULT NUIAPI NuiGetSensorCount( _In_ int * pCount );
   ^
   ...(tons of _Check_return does not name a type)


   c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiImageCamera.h:78:39: error: '_In_'       was not declared in this scope
   c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc/NuiImageCamera.h:78:70: error: '_Out_' was not declared in this scope
   ```

**Questions**

I understand most of these errors(if not all) is because Kinect SDK is intended for VS. But I'm a newbie who wanted to know more about what's going through underneath. So Can I get my g++ to work with Kinect SDK, how?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

By the way, [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=10271.0) is a page related:

Comment: Headers seems to have some gcc incompatibilities :/. You must use `-std=c++11` flag (according to the un-recognized `static_assert`). Since it is C++, use c++ extension (as .cpp) instead of .c . Be aware that libraries may also be incompatibles :-/ Good luck.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for your quick replay. I added -std==c++11 and static_assert was recognized. I think most of these error have something to do with MICROSOFT Sourcecode Annotation Language, I'm trying with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way!
Download **sal.h** and **concurrencysal.h** (find them through a Google search). Put them in the include directory and include sal.h in the program. 
As mentioned above in a comment, add the flag -std==c++11. 
Then open NuiSkeleton.h, and at line 412 and line 534, change NULL to nullptr everywhere (all instances).
It should then run without errors.

Answer (score -1):

you don't seem to grasp that Visual Studio libraries are not out-of-the-box compatible with MinGW. I'm not saying it's -impossible- to use Kinect SDK in MinGW, but what you're trying to do will not work that easily
Two solution, either you don't use Kinect SDK (there are alternatives, such as OpenNI, Freenect...), or you compile your project using Visual Studio (Community Edition is free for personal use)